# The red dots in most IDEs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to vscode and I come from  a [replit](https://replit.com/%7E) background. When I hover my mouse just to the left of a line number, a small red dot appears. When I click in the dot it then stays there until I click it again. I am confused on the purpose of this.

Comment: Debugger breakpoint?

Comment: @lalala If so, what is one?

Comment: Read / watch / work through a few tutorials on how to use your IDE of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red dots that appear by clicking on the left of the line or by pressing F9 on the current line are [vscode breakpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints).
They're used for [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) purposes